# Why are colors brighter and more red on Sony HX100v?

Tags: sony, brightness, color-red

I have purchased a Sony HX100v. Can any one give me a review about its photography results? Till I am not more explore it. One thing I noticed about it was the color. Colors are brighter than actual object and the camera added more red tone. Why does this happen? Any ideas?

Comment: Each brand has his "style". Even if everithing is the same pictures taken with two different cameras look different. I think that Sony focus more on pretty looking colors than on "realistic" colors.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question where a sample image would help us determine the causes of your results. For results others are getting with the same model, [a Flickr search](http://www.flickr.com/search/?q=hx100v) should give plenty of samples.

Without seeing any of your images, the usual suspects are

- wrong [white balance](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3037/what-is-the-meaning-of-white-balance)
- [saturation](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14820/what-do-hue-chroma-saturation-value-tones-tints-shade-etc-mean) setting too high
- the monitor used to assess the results [needs calibration](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10997/do-all-monitors-do-or-need-calibration)

Comment: Also, isn't red one of those colours that confuses metering sensors? I can't recall specific details but remember a bit of a fuss being made when the Canon 7D came out about its new iFCL metering, which handled reds better...

Answer (score 0):

Camera sensors are linear capture devices, which does not match well to the human perception of light and color. So, after the raw image is taken, it is usually converted to something with more "pop" to the color. Since *more pop* equals *more exciting first impression*, most consumer camera models default to cranking these parameters right up to 11.

More advanced models will give a lot of control over this — either as direct control over curves, or as "film emulation", or sometimes as both. On *your* camera, this is known as ***Color mode***, and there's a [section on it in the manual](https://docs.sony.com/release/DSC-HX100_HX100V_guide_EN.pdf). It looks like you have options of *Standard*, *Vivid*, *Real*, or Sepia or B&W.

If your camera is in Vivid mode, that's almost certainly what's going on. But even Standard may be too extreme for your taste, just as the default color options on most TVs are ghastly and toy-like: these settings sell product to consumers who care more about ***AWESOME*** than looking right — let alone good.

As I alluded to above, all of these conversions are happening *after* the raw capture from the sensor. Unfortunately, with your camera, you can't access this RAW data directly, as only JPEG output is supported, so you're stuck with the in-camera conversion options. If you had a camera which can save in a RAW format, you could use the different curve options of your RAW conversion software to get different results which may be more to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

Please check which color profile your camera is set to.

I suspect it be set to 'AdobeRGB' - which may well have the effect you're seeing. To get expected results using anything else than sRGB you need to set up a **properly** color-managed workflow.